# Images not in the project folder

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I had uploaded a build on iTunes connect. But all the images weren't in the project folder. I tried running the app on my iPhone and it worked fine.

Are there going to be any issues?

Comment: nope it is fine they are stored in assets

Comment: Are they automatically copied in the assets if I dragged them in the Xcode?

Comment: yep they will stored as assets as you must have set the target for that file

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how do I set the target?

Comment: check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35793194/2963912

Comment: Because the location of the image shown in the xcose is my desktop folder

Comment: when you add code in sourcecontrol maintain the copy in folder of project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the target of that assets, it will automatically copies to the iPA

[image]

When you add any file do not forget to tick the check box for copy

[image]

Comment: Where can I locate my image in the project folder?

Comment: you can add that files to assets folder

Comment: Ok, so it won't be added automatically if I drag and drop from the finder to the xcode? But, it will be copied to the iPA. Right?

Comment: I have updated the answer so that files automatically copied to project folder

Comment: Got it! I had not ticked that "Copy items if needed" thing. Thanks!!

But as I have uploaded the build in the iTunes Connect already, should there be any problem?